# How do I get the value of the Authorization key from the site?

Tags: python-requests, authorization

Good afternoon. I log in to one site using my username/ password

I pulled an *unofficial API* from the site. Registration on a direct request to him with the transfer of JSON was successful

But further use of the API requires the **Authorization** key -
[see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cIHDs.jpg)

How do I get it and use it for API requests? I tried to get cookies, but nothing changes with them

*I just started learning request and stopped right there, sorry if the question is stupid and I'm wasting your time*

Answer (score 0):

Reading the documentation is a powerful tool that programmer must leverage you can see in Requests documentation they already gave you the example

```
r = requests.get('https://api.github.com/user', auth=('user', 'pass'))
r.status_code
>>> 200
r.headers['content-type']
>>> application/json; charset=utf8
```